# If statement and how to stop it

Tags: python

I have a question regarding the if statement. I have an if statement within a function. Here I determine that when my variable is lower than 0, it should just print one specific sentence but stop here. So the function should not go on and stop here.
How can I do that?

```
def __init__(self, business account ): 
  self.business = business 
  if account < 0:
    print('The balance is negative, therefore an account cannot be created!') #break 
  else:
    self.account = account
```

Comment: That is what `return` is intended for.

Comment: You need to add an example of your code to get an answer.

Comment: def __init__(self, business account ):
        self.business = business
        if account < 0:
           print('The balance is negative, therefore an account cannot be created!')
           #break
        else:
            self.account = account

Comment: As here, where #break is now. How can I stop here?

Answer (score 1):

`return` stops a function. You can return something and the function will terminate. Also the question is a bit unclear, try rephrasing it.

Comment: So the code in the following should stop when balance <0:
    
    def __init__(self, amount, balance = 0):
        self.amount = amount
        if balance < 0:
           print('The balance is negative, therefore an account cannot be created!')
           #XXXX
        else:
            self.balance = balance
                                 
    def know_amount(self):
        return self.owner 
    
    def know_balance(self):
        return self.balance
  
    def deposition(self, amount):
        self.balance +=amount
        print('Amount Deposited:', amount)